# Serialize and Deserialize Cosmos DB document property as string

Tags: json.net, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Json.Net to decorate my document properties.

```
public class MyDocumentType : Document
{
    [JsonProperty]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public MyEnumType EnumProertyName{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public uint MyIntPrperty{ get; set; }
}
```

When I update the document in cosmos db, it is not getting updated to string value. It is always defaulting to the default enum value. How do I make it serialize and deserialize to string value. I don't want to use numbers as if I add a new enum value then things will break.

Comment: I've just tested your code and it seems to be working fine with both Replace and Upsert method. `EnumProertyName` is always a string.

Comment: @Raghav Please add your client code and error you met.

Comment: @JayGong I haven't got any error. It simply doesn't serialize to the value I set and always serializes tot he default value. I got rid of the error by not inheriting from Document ans creating a simple POCO that has the id property and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 7):

With Cosmos DB SDK 3+, you cannot pass `JsonSerializerSettings` directly.

You would need to extend `CosmosSerializer`. You can get the an example of `CosmosSerializer` implementation from [CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Encryption/src/CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer.cs) in Cosmos DB SDK.

Unfortunately, this class is `internal` `sealed` so you may have copy verbatim in your code. I have also raised a GitHub issue asking the Cosmos team to address this issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1813).

Once, you have an implementation for CosmosSerializer available in your code, you can pass `JsonSerializerSettings` as below:

```
// Create CosmosClientOptions
var cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions
                {
                    Serializer =
                   new CosmosJsonDotNetSerializer(
                      new JsonSerializerSettings() {
                          // Your JSON Serializer settings
                      })
                 };

var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(connectionString, cosmosClientOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

When constructing `DocumentClient` object you are allowed to pass `JsonSerializerSettings` object. In that object you need to add handling of string values like this:

```
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            DateFormatString = "o",
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,

            Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
            {
                new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter()
                {
                    AllowIntegerValues = true
                }
            },
        };
```

`StringEnumConverter` - this should serialize/deserialize your enums to string, while also allow to parse back from int.